# Filter CloudWatch logs with a property selector for a JSON property containing a period character "."

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

How would I write a CloudWatch filter with a property selector for a JSON property containing a period character `"."`?

The CloudWatch documentation describes using a property selector to filter log data (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#metric-filters-extract-json):

**Documentation Syntax**:
`{ PropertySelector EqualityOperator String }`

**Documentation Example**:
`{ $.eventType = "UpdateTrail" }`

If a log event contains a JSON property containing a period character `"."`, is it possible to describe it with a property selector?

I have attempted the following property selectors:

1. Filter encounters error `{ $.attributes.http\.method = "POST" }`
2. Filter encounters error `{ $.attributes["http.method"] = "POST" }`
3. Filter produces zero results `{ $.attributes.http.method = "POST" }`

Example Event

```
{
    "traceId": "75e07edf6f50ddf0d4a8239cbe91d60a",
    "parentId": "f8875623e2e77de4",
    "name": "request handler - /subscriptions",
    "id": "7f8b38dcbbb15983",
    "kind": 0,
    "timestamp": 1673621283065,
    "duration": 3,
    "attributes": {
        "http.route": "/subscriptions",
        "express.name": "/subscriptions",
        "express.type": "request_handler",
        "http.method": "POST",
        "http.url": "/subscriptions",
        "http.body": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
    },
    "status": {
        "code": 0
    },
    "events": [],
    "links": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the property selector has a period in it, you'll need to access it using the bracket notation. So what you would need to do is:

```
{ $.attributes.['http.method'] = "POST" }
```

You can find this information in their [pattern filter documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#matching-terms-json-log-events) under "Match terms in JSON log events using simple expressions" you can find a similar example